# I have read the yii documentation but did not get my answer yet,

Tags: yii

I have small question at here I have read the yii documentation but did not get my answer yet, I want to fetch one table column in select option in the form how can I do this in yii framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'my_id',CHtml::listData(OptionsModel::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'title')),'id','title'),array('prompt' => 'Please select')); ?>
```